# Multiple SMS Threads

Tags: sms

I have been having a problem with the default SMS client recently and haven't found a solution yet. The problem is that when I am texting with certain friends, there will be two threads going: one thread for texts I receive from them, and one thread for texts I send. The problem has always occurred when I first text someone but it is the wrong number (I type the wrong area code by mistake). The person obviously does not receive the text, but when I change the contact's number and text to the correct phone I get all of their replies from the number I originally typed in, which causes two threads for the same person.

I was hoping that somebody might be able to provide an answer for essentially merging the two threads. I have a Samsung Galaxy Slide and it runs on Android 2.3.5 (Gingerbread). Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Have an entry in 'Contacts' for each one of your friends (Contact -> Add new contact, then enter their number and details) and then enter SMS chat with them any time by entering into their respective 'Contacts' profile and clicking on the 'Send Message' icon to begin SMS chat.

Or just use an Chatting app like WhatsApp which has native support for all modern mobile OS's (Android, Blackberry, iOS..) so you could avoid retyping the same number again and again.

Or just stop mistyping those area codes.

Comment: I would love to stop mistyping those area codes, but what's done is done. I have my friends in my contacts, the problem is that the first number I had typed in their profile was wrong; now their replies always end up in the thread that contains the original number I typed. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried deleting both threads ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it once. The problem still occurs when they text me back.

Comment: Well, I did a little research and found it to be a bug in the default sms app, without any solution.
However I may have found a something that may or may not work, try http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1227352